# LISTAGG function to concatenate strings and search for explicit string values in Redshift does not work

Tags: sql, select, amazon-redshift, listagg

I have a table project. I would like to concatenate all projects per id in one row and filter for only for ids which do have the project 'a' but not the project 'c'.

Table: project

| id | project |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | d |

Result

| id | project |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | a,b,d |

I tried several approaches, among others this one:

```sql
SELECT
  id, 
  LISTAGG(project, ',') AS project
  FROM project
  WHERE project NOT IN ('c') AND project in ('a')
  GROUP BY id
```

Or

```sql
SELECT
  id, 
  LISTAGG(project, ',') AS project
  FROM project
  WHERE project != 'c' AND project = 'a'
  GROUP BY id
```

Or this one:

```sql
SELECT id, 
       LISTAGG(project, ',') 
       FROM (
            SELECT person_id,
                   project
            FROM project
            WHERE project IN 
                           (
                            SELECT project
                            FROM project
                            WHERE project != 'c' AND project = 'a'
                            )
             )
       GROUP BY id
```

All of the above approaches do not filter properly and do not exclude ids with project 'c'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're grouping the result anyway (for the `listagg`), a neat trick is to count the occurrences of `'a'` (should be more than 0) and `'c'` (should be exactly 0):

```sql
SELECT   id,  LISTAGG(project, ',') AS project
FROM     project
GROUP BY id
HAVING   COUNT(CASE project WHEN 'a' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
         COUNT(CASE project WHEN 'c' THEN 1 END) = 0
```